# Is there a way to get an "extension board" for a Polycom IP6000 phone?

Tags: networking, hardware, voip, telephony, polycom

I don't see any for sale, but is there a way to get one hooked up to it? Basically, I need 15+ speed dials.

Something like this would be great, but for the Polycom instead of Grandstream:

[image: extension board]
http://www.grandstream.com/files/3412/9650/0315/GXP20202EXT.jpg

Comment: Reach out to inside sales rep at [polycom](http://www.polycom.com/forms/contact_polycom.html).  This is probably your best bet in finding a proper solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get [these](http://www.polycom.com/products/voice/desktop_solutions/soundpoint/accessories/soundpoint_ip_color_expansion_module.html) for many of the SoundPoint IP range of Polycom phones, but AFAIK, I don't believe you can get them for the conference phones (which I believe the 6000 is)